# How can I easily design my coffee with coffee maker?

Tags: substitute-tool

I would like to design my coffee with shapes like hearts or any other possible shapes using the coffee creamer but I find it hard. Any suggestion?

I've tried creating a design in a typewriting, putting it in the top of coffee cup (I've already put coffee and hot water in it) then pouring a 1 teaspoon of creamer on it. The results is not good, I didn't achieved the the heart shape design.

Comment: What you are looking for is called "Latte Art" or more generically "Coffee Art" and it is simply a skill that has to be learned (like any other art). There are a lot of videos about this on the net and it is written about extensively. As such, this isn't really a life hack as scoped out for this site. Sorry about the confusion, but good luck with your project. It is fun to do!